# Does defining the closure of a set as the intersection of all closed set that contain it requires the axiom of choice?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Given a set $S$, the closure of $S$ is sometimes defined as the intersection of all the closed sets that contain it. This type of argument is pervasive in mathematics when one want to construct the smallest object that still verifies some property.

Does this require the axiom of choice? What makes it possible to construct such intersection?

Comment: Why do you think it invokes the Axiom of Choice?

Comment: I don't know. It is just that the argument feels a little odd. Why can I build such thing as the intersection of an uncountable infinite number of sets with some property?

Comment: Perhaps you're uncomfortable with [impredicativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impredicativity).

Answer (score 2):

No. Let $S\subseteq X$ be a set, and $\tau$ be the topology on $X$. Then
$$\overline{S} = \left\{x\in S: \forall (T\subseteq S : X\setminus T\in \tau)[x\in T]\right\}$$
All we are using here is the [axiom schema of specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification).

Answer (score 2):

Not everything uncountable, or infinite, requires the axiom of choice. The axiom of choice comes into play when we have to actually make choices.

In the case of a topological closure we don't have to make choices. We don't have to choose *some* closed sets which include $S$ in order to generate the closure. We take *all* of them. Taking all of them doesn't require any choice, because we can define what it means for a set to include $S$ and be closed, so the entire collection is definable and we can prove it's not empty, because the space itself is always a closed set including $S$.